# Does it make sense to use memcache with a static site?

Tags: memcached, jekyll, static-site

If I correctly understand how the whole memcache technology works, it caches queries to an external component of a website, most often a database. But a static site does not use a database. So does it make sense to use memcache with a static side framework such as Jekyll and Octopress?

Answer (score 2):

You're better off using Nginx and/or Varnish if your site is mostly static. The typical use case for memcached is for caching database data, it's not limited to that, but Varnish in particular is great for caching entire HTML pages and all of its associated static content (js, css, images, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can use. u can cache entire page. all depends on your application

Comment: Would you please elaborate a bit on this? In what way does a static page take advantage of memcachier?